# JavaScript: Increment Variable value on click relative to parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, onclick, click

I have a complicated question, so I will try and keep it as short as possible.

My use-case is building an RSS feed for a mobile website. The interface will be similar to Pulse reader only browser based.

I am doing the heavy lifting with PHP for connecting to the XML API and pulling in the initial data on page load.  I am trying to build an AJAX call with jQuery that will modify my URI query string on `click()` and pull in a fresh set of results and append them to my existing elements.

My URI looks something like this:

`http://www.domain.com/request.php?subcategoryId=1&page=1`

I am running a PHP `foreach()` loop to populate my page:

```
<?php // Collect Subcategories and Titles
 foreach ($phpObjects->SubcategoryResult as $SubcategoryResult) { ?>

<?php // Callback to subcategoryArticleRequest() to recieve article data
 $subcategoryObjects = subcategoryArticleRequest($SubcategoryResult->subcategoryId); ?>

<div class="subcategory">
  <h2><?php echo $SubcategoryResult->subcategoryName; ?></h2>
  <div class="articleFeed overthrow">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <?php foreach ($subcategoryObjects->articleResult as $articleResult) { ?>
        <td>

          <!-- ARTICLE CONTENT POPULATED HERE -->

        </td>
        <?php } ?>

        <td data-subcategoryId="<?php echo $SubcategoryResult->subcategoryId; ?>" onClick="page++">
          <a class="loadMore" href="#">Load More</a>
        </td>

      </tr>
    </table>
  </div><!-- .articleFeed -->
</div>
<?php } ?>
```

The main area of focus would be this element I am appending to the table after the foreach runs.  I will be using this link to click and load more articles through AJAX (I have hard-coded `data-subcategoryId` here):

```
<td data-subcategoryId="1">
  <a class="loadMore" href="#">Load More</a>
</td>
```

In essence when someone clicks this button, it will make an AJAX call and retrieve `&page=2` and so on.

Here's my JavaScript:

```
var page = 1;

$('.loadMore').click(function() {
  page++;
  var subcategoryId = $(this).parent().attr('data-subcategoryId');
  var url = 'http://www.domain.com/request.php?subcategoryId='+subcategoryId+'&page='+page;

  console.log(url);
});
```

The issue I keep running into is that when I click on the `.loadMore` link, it will increment the `page` variable, but it will do it globally.  If I try moving the `var page = 1;` inside the click function, it will only increment once to `2`.

Once I get this function right, I can pass the `url` variable to my AJAX function for pulling in the fresh content.

Ive set up a JSFiddle just in case, though it keeps showing subcategoryId as undefined:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jd657/12/)

Comment: I don't understand why you got down voted, because you have clearly tried and shows what you have tried. You also set up a fiddle. Excellent! Oh, and it looks like the answer from `gray state is coming` should solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you for the kind words.  It was a tough problem to articulate.  Not to mention I had been staring at the same block of code all day, so my brain was turning to mush.  Gonna deflate a bit longer than try `gray state is coming`'s answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it sounds like each element should have its own `page` variable.

An easy solution is to use `.each()` to assign the handlers, and create the `page` variable inside the `each` callback.

```
$('.loadMore').each(function() {

    var page = 1;

    $(this).click(function() {
      page++;
      var subcategoryId = $(this).parent().attr('data-subcategoryId');
      var url = 'http://www.domain.com/request.php?subcategoryId='+subcategoryId+'&page='+page;

      console.log(url);
    });

});
```

Because JavaScript functions are closures, each `.click` handler has been created in its own fresh variable environment, and each handler will always have reference to the variables that were in scope at the time of creation.

This means that each handler has its own personal `page` variable to increment.

Another solution would be to use "event data". You can associate data with a particular element via the `event` object.

```
$('.loadMore').each(function() {
    $(this).bind("click", {page:1}, loadMoreHandler);
});

function loadMoreHandler(e) {
  e.data.page++;
  var subcategoryId = $(this).parent().attr('data-subcategoryId');
  var url = 'http://www.domain.com/request.php?subcategoryId='+subcategoryId+'&page='+e.data.page;

  console.log(url);
}
```

Since a closure is no longer taken advantage of, I used a named function for the handler for the sake of function object reuse. You can change it back to an anonymous function if it doesn't matter to you.

Comment: Excellent response!  Thorough explanation, as well as the alternative solution make this my accepted answer.  I also like that I don't have to modify my HTML. +1

Comment: It has come to my attention that although this works great in desktop, it is not collecting the `click()` event on my touch device.  Any thoughts?

Comment: @stat30fbliss: I haven't programmed for touch devices, but I've heard that the click event takes longer to register. I think there are workarounds using other event types. You'll want to do a bit of research on touch based event handling.

Answer (score 1):

add new data to :

```
<td data-subcategoryId="1" data-page="1">
```

then increment `page` and update the `data-page`:

```
$('.loadMore').click(function() {
  var page = $(this).parent().data('page');
  page++;
  $(this).parent().data('page',page);
  ...
```

Comment: I really appreciate the response! Although your solution works well, I prefer not having to add another data attribute to my code for now. +1 and thank you!